# GAE sending CSV file through POST gives error 500

Tags: python, google-app-engine, csv, blobstore

I'm trying to make an endpoint for my GAE application, where I can problematically send a POST request with a CSV file (as a form) from a client, and then the server will receive it, and store it in Datastore. However, when I try to send a large file, it times out. It seems that the max URL fetch timeout is 59.9 seconds, and that's where it fails.

```
class CostTest(ndb.Model):
pickUp = ndb.StringProperty()
amount = ndb.StringProperty()

def post(self):
    self.response.write("part 1")
    print self.request.get('type')

    check_values = self.request.POST.getall('file')
    array = list(csv.reader(check_values))
    for c in array:
        pickup, amount = c
        entry = CostTest(pickUp=pickup,
                         amount=amount)
        entry.put()

        #print c
    self.response.write("part 2")
    self.response.write(self.request.get('file'))

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
('/csv/order', CsvFileLoader),
('/csv/kiosk', CsvFileLoader)
], debug=True)
```

The file that I'm using to test has ~4600 rows, however, it's unable to load them all! I tried using Blobstore, however I cannot figure out how to get a file from a POST request (if at all possible?). It seems like the only way to store into blob store is through a user submitted form!

Thanks for the help, in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is not "load them all", but you're doing 4600 synchronous puts! If you batch all of them and use ndb.put_multi, I believe it works. A python script can replicate submitted form, what problem do you have with uploading to blobstore?

Comment: I'll look into the put_multi! When using blobstore, I can't seem to "capture"(is that the correct term?) the CSV file. When I try to store it, it gives me an error saying the list is empty.

Comment: Hmm, I tried using the put_multi, and it's definitely faster...however, I'm afraid that in production, it will still go over the 60 second limit with larger files.

Comment: If you upload to blobstore, the file will be uploaded to blobstore, what are you trying to do? How big is "larger"? Why would you generate thousands of entities per request? That does not seem the right thing to do.

Comment: Basically, I'm trying to upload the CSV file to Blobstore, and then eventually get it exported to Big Query to analyis. From what I've been reading, you must go Datastore -> Create a backup to Cloud Storage -> export that to Big Query.

Comment: why don't you insert directly to bigquery? I believe you can write a python script and execute it on localhost to insert to bigquery. Or the easier solution is to analyze the csv using pandas and ipython on localhost. Why do you need to put it in bigquery anyway?

Comment: Oh really?? We have a MongoDB hosted on some Google cloud service..so I need to take that DB Dump, and send it off to BigQuery, where I use some queries and Google Charts to present the data.

I'm an intern at a company.. so I'm learning as I go...so It's gettin' a little tough!

Answer (score 1):

Even if you "sometimes" meet the 60s HTTP requests limit, the GAE Datastore can randomly take much longer to process reads and writes, so I would suggest storing the uploaded CSV file somewhere first (the blobstore you mentioned or even as another datastore entity, just mind the size limit) and then process it asynchronously using a task queue (limit for that is 10 minutes).